# Freeing raw image data after creating a UIImage from it, corrupts image

Tags: ios, iphone, c, cocoa-touch, core-foundation

I am taking a UIImage, breaking it down to the raw Pixel Data like so

```
CGImageRef imageRef = self.image.CGImage;
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
_rawData = (UInt8 *)calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(UInt8));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(_rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

I then edit a couple pixels in the _rawData array with different colors, then re-create the UIImage like this from the edited _rawData pixel data like so. (In this, I am just changing the second pixel in the image to be red)

```
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(_image.CGImage);
NSUInteger pixel = 1; // second pixel
NSUInteger position = pixel*4;
NSUInteger redIndex = position;
NSUInteger greenIndex = position+1;
NSUInteger blueIndex = position+2;
NSUInteger alphaIndex = position+3;

_rawData[redIndex] = 255;
_rawData[greenIndex] = 0;
_rawData[blueIndex] = 0;
_rawData[alphaIndex] = 255;

size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(_image.CGImage);
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
size_t bytesPerRow = 4*width;
size_t length = height*width*4;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, _rawData, length, NULL);

CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
```

My problem begins here: I now have a new UIImage that has the second pixel changed to red, but I have a memory leak. I need to free the _rawData that has been calloc'd. Whenever I call

```
free(_rawData);
```

even though its after i've already created my "newImage".  That image I just created is corrupted when I show it on screen. I thought that CGImageCreate() would create a new object in memory so then I could free the old memory. Is that not true?

What in the world I am doing wrong?

Comment: How does the image look corrupted? This is an obvious question, but if you comment out the free call, is the image still corrupted?

Comment: Yessir. Everything works great if I don't have the free(_rawData) call. The image actually changes  every time I run the app with the free call in there. Sometimes its only the first few pixels that are screwed up, sometimes its the last few. On rare occasions the entire  image is blank except for a couple pixels that aren't even close to the same colors that were supposed to be in the image.

Comment: Hmm, what thread are you running it on? Are you testing on device or simulator?

Comment: Simulator. Everything is on the main thread right now.

Comment: I just tested on the device as well. Same problem

Comment: Just attached a sample project to the original question for clarity.

Comment: Hmm, I tried your sample project with a different image and it worked fine. The issue doesn't seem to be how you free memory, rather your configuration settings for the CGImageContexts.

Comment: Hmm.. was the other image a PNG?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't have an alpha channel.

Comment: Ah okay, all the images i'll be working with will have an alpha channel.